# How would you subscribe from an epic?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have an epic that pipes actions into a subject representing a WebSocket, like so:

```
const webSocketSendEpic = (action$, state$, { socket }) =>
  action$.ofType('SEND_MESSAGE')
    .pluck('payload')
    .subscribe(socket)
```

However, this is not a true epic as it returns a `Subscription` instead of an `Observable`. I could circumvent this by surrounding it with a block and returning `EMPTY`, but this doesn't feel correct. What is the correct way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to connect the socket using `do`, instead of `subscribe` and then treat it as you would any other epic:

```
const webSocketSendEpic = (action$, state$, { socket }) =>
  action$.ofType('SEND_MESSAGE')
    .pluck('payload')
    .do(socket)
    .ignoreElements();
```

And you could use `ignoreElements` to prevent the epic from emitting the plucked payload.